# Can a library generated with Angular-CLI 8 be safely used with an Angular 2, 4, 5, 6 or 7 application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, backwards-compatibility, angular-library

I develop and provide an Angular library through NPM. This library is currently being built by some hand made scripts when Angular 5 was the norm.
This library has no problematic peerDependancies (such as RxJS) so it is compatible as is with Angular 5 to 8 applications.

I plan to migrate my build system to Angular CLI 8. It works nice. However, I worry that some users of my library that have included it into Angular 5, 6 or 7 applications may encounter problems because, at least, it will be built with the new Angular Package Format v8.

Does anyone know if backward compatibility is assured for Angular CLI based libraries?

Answer (score 0):

No, apparently it can't be used. If a library is compiled with v8, it will work with angular 8 and above, because there might be certain angular 8 features that might not work in angular 7. Hence the library can't be guaranteed to work with 7 as well.